# Getting number of records in mysql inconsistency

Tags: mysql, query

When i check the number of records in a MySQL table using "show table status like 'table_name", the number of rows given is different from the number of rows when i run "select count(*)" on the same table.

I would like to know why the number is different, and what each number means.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why from the MySQL Documentation:

> The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the
>   exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is
>   an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40%
>   to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate
>   count.
>
> The Rows value is NULL for INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables.
>
> For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL
>   optimization. (This is also true if the InnoDB table is partitioned.)